Understand verse Isaiah 29:12
I am currently in the process of understanding various religions and studying them.
While studying the Quran's English translation, I came across this footnote about this verse
96:5 عَلَّمَ ٱلْإِنسَـٰنَ مَا لَمْ يَعْلَمْ ٥

taught humanity what they knew not.1  — Dr. Mustafa Khattab, The
Clear Quran
Verses 1-5 are known to be the first ever revealed of the Quran.
The Prophet (ﷺ) was retreating at a cave in the outskirts of Mecca
when the angel Gabriel appeared to him, squeezing him tightly and
ordering him to read. Since the Prophet (ﷺ) was unlettered, he
responded, “I cannot read.” Ultimately, Gabriel taught him: “Read in
the Name of your Lord …” Some scholars believe that this encounter is
the fulfilment of Isaiah 29:12, which states, “Then the book will be
given to the one who is illiterate, saying, ‘Read this.’ And he will
say, ‘I cannot read.’”

I explored Isaiah 29:12 but couldn't understand it much because maybe I could not get the right/clear translation for this verse. Please help me understand Isaiah 29:12. Does it really mean that a holy book will be given by God to someone illiterate in the future?

Recommended reading: https://apologeticspress.org/has-the-bible-been-transmitted-to-us-accurately-5732/  and   https://apologeticspress.org/muhammad-or-jesus-5135/   and  https://apologeticspress.org/the-quran-vs-the-new-testament-conflicting-ethics-1585/   and https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/10/07/the-one-true-god-but-there-are-two-of-them-allah-or-yahweh/   The Quran affirms the Bible as the scriptures of God & then contradicts them.  God cannot speak against himself.

If users of the Quran want to interpret the prophecy of Isa 29 as applying to Mohammad and his contemporaries, then the following will also apply:

V1: it is the place where David camped
V9, 10: blind yourselves and be sightless; be drunk, but not with wine; tagger, but not from strong drink. For the LORD has poured out on you a spirit of deep sleep. He has shut your eyes, O prophets; He has covered your heads, O seers.
V13, 14 - Therefore the Lord said: “These people draw near to Me with their mouths and honor Me with their lips, but their hearts are far from Me. Their worship of Me is but rules taught by men. Therefore I will again confound these people with wonder upon wonder. The wisdom of the wise will vanish, and the intelligence of the intelligent will be hidden.

This is NOT flattering stuff!  It is a prophecy about sinful and rebellious Judah who became "drunk" with foreign gods and spiritually "blind" with disobedience.  That is why they could not "read"/"understand" (as the Hebrew implies).

Ok! I see. Thanks! However I am still gonna keep this question open in case someone else wants to answer on this.

Verse 12 of Isaiah 29 is not a prophecy, but rather an explanation of a vision (prophecy) against the city of Ariel. The prophecy reads from verses 2 to 7:

Yet I will besiege Ariel; she will mourn and lament... The hordes of all the nations that fight against Ariel, that attack her and her fortress and besiege her, will be as it is with a dream, with a vision in the night.

Verse 11 starts by explaining that no one can understand the prophecy/vision written above.

For you this whole vision is nothing but words sealed in a scroll.

This means that whoever is receiving or reading about this vision cannot understand its meaning; the same way that someone who can read won't be able to read a sealed scroll because they cannot see inside (like reading a folded letter inside an envelope).

And if you give the scroll to someone who can read... they will answer "I can't; it is sealed".

Similarly, someone who cannot read, won't even attempt to read the scroll

Or if you give the scroll to someone who cannot read... they will answer "I don't know how to read."

There is no mention of a coming prophet to whom the vision will be explained in this passage. So no, this passage is not about reading or not reading, but about a prophecy that no one can interpret because the Lord has not revealed its meaning to anyone. Not even the prophets because He has blinded them, nor the seers because He has covered their heads.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Eddy. If you haven't already, please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Answer
Isaiah 29:12 does not at all mean that a holy Book will be given by God to someone illiterate and non-Israelite in the future because of the following reasons.
Explanation
Apostle Paul asks:

“Do the Jews then have any advantage over the Gentiles? (Rom 3:1).

He himself answers the question:

“Much in every way. To begin with, the Jews were entrusted with the
Oracles of God” (verse 2).

In fact, God revealed His Word only to the children of Israel and especially to the Jews. God did not do this for other peoples.

“He declares His Word to Jacob, His statutes and His judgments
to Israel. He has not dealt with any other nation like this; they never knew His decrees. Hallelujah!” (Psalms 147:19-20).

So, it is a false claim that some other illiterate person from some other gentile nation received the revelation from the true God. (They make so many such false claims!)
The True God & Literacy and Knowledge
In fact, we can see that the true God promotes literacy and education among His people (especially holy men who received the Word of God) right from the beginning.

“And Jehovah said to Moses, Write this, a memorial in a book”
(Exo 17:14).


“And Joshua wrote these words in the book of the Law of God”
(Joshua 24:26).


And Samuel spoke to the people the duties of the kingdom, and
wrote in the book” (1 Sam 10:25).


“And it happened in the morning David wrote a letter to Joab” (2
Sam 11:14).


“And Jehovah said to me (Isaiah), Take a big tablet and write
in it” (Isaiah 8:1).

(These are only a very few samples from a lot many).
So, we see that God is not a God of ignorance and illiteracy but He is a God of literacy and knowledge. We see that all of His holy men are literate and knowledgeable.
Isaiah 29:12
Isaiah 29:12 is not a stand-alone verse; it is part of a whole discourse from God.
As part of giving a benefit of doubt, I am going to apply this entire discourse as applying to that prophet (referred as “Mhmd”) of the other religion:

‘"Act stupid! Be astonished! Act blind, and be blind! Be drunk, but
not from wine; stagger around, but not from strong drink. For the LORD
has poured out upon you (Mhmd) a spirit of deep sleep—He has
closed your (Mhmd) eyes, you prophet, He has covered your
(Mhmd) heads, you seer!" "And this entire vision has become for
you (Mhmd) like the words of a sealed book. When people give it to someone who can read, and say, 'Read this, please,' he (Mhmd)
answers, 'I cannot, because it is sealed.' Or when they give the book
to someone who cannot read, and say, 'Read this, please,' he
(Mhmd) answers, 'I don't know how to read.'" Then the Lord said:
"Because this Mhmd draws near with his mouth and honor Me with his
lips, but his heart is far from Me, worship of Me has become merely
like rules taught by human beings. Therefore, watch out!’ (Isaiah
29:9-14; paraphrased for clarity).

It is crystal clear that God is talking about His people Israel including the prophets who have all gone astray.
If this could be applied to that prophet, then he is not from God. That is, He is not a true prophet of God if Isaiah 29:12 is applied to him.
Conclusion

“For I could wish that I myself were accursed and cut off from Christ
for the sake of my brothers (Israelites), my kinsmen (Jews) according
to the flesh. They are Israelites, and to them belong the
adoption, the glory, the covenants, the giving of the law, the worship, and the promises. To them belong the patriarchs, and from their race, according to the flesh, is the Christ, who is God over all, blessed forever. Amen” (Rom 9:3-5).

Yes, God’s Revelation is entrusted only to the Jews and none else!
Jesus Christ says:

“You worship what you do not know; we worship what we know, for
salvation is from the Jews” (John 4:22).

Even in the Millennium, the coming New World Order, God leads other nations through the Jews:

"When this happens, ten people from nations with different languages
will grab a Jew by his clothes and say, "Let us go with you. We've
heard that God is on your side." I, the LORD All-Powerful, have
spoken!" (Zechariah 8:23).


